# UnitOfWork with lazy loading and multiple data source

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure-sql-database, azure-storage

I have business objects that are stored across two data storages. A part of the object is stored in Azure Table Storage and the other part in Azure SQL. Basically the SQL part is used in queries while the Table Storage is used for properties that take a lot of space.

Most of the times, only the SQL part of the object is used (in SQL queries). The Table Storage properties are only needed when someone explicitly asks for that object. What I am trying to achieve is a design that will hide the fact that there are two data sources behind the business object, lazy load the Storage Table properties (since they are not needed when performing SQL queries) and still make the code testable.

My current design has some POCOs that are created by a unit of work. I don't want to create two POCOs, one for Table Storage and one for SQL, so I was thinking about the following design:

```
//Make the properties virtual
public class Customer
{
    public virtual string Name {get;set;} //Stored in SQL
    public virtual string Age {get;set;} //Stored in SQL
    public virtual string Details {get;set;} // This prop is stored in Table Storage
}

//Create a derived internal POCO that can notify when a property is asked
internal class CustomerWithMultipleStorage
{
    public event EventHandler OnDetailsGet;

    public override string Details
    {
         get { if (OnDetailsGet!=null) OnDetailsGet( ... ); /* rest of the code */ }
         set { /* code */ }
    }
}
```

All my data layer code will work with `CustomerWithMultipleStorage` while all the "external" code, outside the DL, will use `Customer` and the events will not be exposed. Now, when the unit of work returns a `Customer`, it will load only the SQL properties and subscribe to the Get events. If someone using the Customer needs the rest of the properties, the event will be triggered and the Table Storage properties will be loaded.

What do you think about this design? Is it the correct approach? Do you know of a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You *could* use `Lazy<T>` with dependency injection. Note this is just to give you some ideas.

```
internal class CustomerWithMultipleStorage : Customer
{
    private readonly ISqlDataLayer _sqlDataLayer;
    private readonly ITableStorageDataLayer _tableStorageDataLayer;
    private readonly Lazy<string> _details;
    private string _detailsValue;

    public CustomerWithMultipleStorage(ISqlDataLayer sqlDataLayer, ITableStorageDataLayer tableStorageDataLayer)
    {
        _sqlDataLayer = sqlDataLayer;
        _tableStorageDataLayer = tableStorageDataLayer;

        _details = new Lazy<string>(() => return (string)_tableStorageDataLayer.GetValue<Customer>(this, "Details"));
    }

    public override string Details
    {
         get
         {
            return (_detailsValue ?? (_detailsValue = _details.Value));
         }
         set
         {
            _detailsValue = value;
            _tableStorageDataLayer.SetValue<Customer>(this, _detailsValue);
         }
    }
}

public interface ITableStorageDataLayer
{
    object GetValue<T>(T item, [CallerMemberName] string property = "");
    void SetValue<T>(T item, object value, [CallerMemberName] string property = "");
}
```

You could also just use a data layer with mapping data for each object (I will provide examples later).